# gRPC client not connected with gRPC service in Docker image

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, grpc

I deployed a gRPC service into a docker image after that I want to the client app connect to the gRPC service unfortunately it didn't work then I got this error message ! I have no idea about that what is wrong with docker file.

```
var ch = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:49155");
```

The error message

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable",
> Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception. IOException:
> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.",
> DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception.  --->
> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the
> transport stream.    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean
> isApm)    at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Nullable`1 timeout)")'

Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GrpcServiceApp/GrpcServiceApp.csproj", "GrpcServiceApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GrpcServiceApp/GrpcServiceApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GrpcServiceApp"
RUN dotnet build "GrpcServiceApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GrpcServiceApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrpcServiceApp.dll"]
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "GrpcServiceApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5220;https://localhost:7220",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

The gRPC service image ports on docker
[image]

Comment: *The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.* can you share the inner exception?

Comment: where is the client running? Inside another docker container?. The Dockerfile you have provided, is the one for the grpc service or the client one ?

Comment: @Jens I updated the error message section please take a look and I pasted all error message

Comment: @usuario the client app is not running inside the docker container just I run it locally in visual studio. do you have any solution ? thanks

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have the same issue for the same scenario. Running a .NET 6 grpc server in a docker container locally, then a .NET 6 grpc client from visual studio on the same local machine. Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream